# Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement 9

Tags: c#

I got this error for the code below it relates to devexpress themes

```
 public WeatherForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register;
        DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [`Register`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument2533) and [`EnableFormSkins`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressSkinsSkinManager_EnableFormSkinstopic) are methods. That's why you need to use it with `()` at the end like;

```
public WeatherForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
    DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
}
```

Before writing more code, I *strongly* suggest read a good C# book in a beginner level.

Answer (score 1):

Both lines after `InitializeComponent()` should be methods.

```
DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register();
DevExpress.Skins.SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
```

> The compiler generates an error when it encounters an invalid statement. An invalid statement is any line or series of lines ending in a semicolon that does not represent an assignment (=), method call (), new, -- or ++ operation. For more information, see Statements, Expressions, and Operators (C# Programming Guide).

MSDN link on the error https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k626bk8b.aspx